# Converting dict comprehension into normal form

Tags: python

I need to convert this in normal for loop form how can i do this

```
read = {
    year: {
         month: read_data_of_a_month(path) for month in months
    }
    for year in range(2000,2013)
}
```

Comment: Start with the innermost and work your way out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a nested for loop:

```
read = {}
for year in range(2000, 2013):
    year_dict = {}
    for month in months:
        year_dict[month] = read_data_of_a_month(path)
    read[year] = year_dict
```

Answer (score -1):

```
read = {}
for year in range(2000, 2013):
    m = {}
    for month in months:
        m[month] = read_data_of_a_month(path)
    read[year] = m
```